# Tensorflow optimizers protest about some indices

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

I have the following graph network:

```
initia = tf.zeros_initializer
I = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name='I') # input
W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[1,DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
O = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(I, W) + b, name='O')
O_0 = tf.gather_nd(O, [0,0])
W_1 = tf.gather_nd(W, [0,1])
distance = tf.square( O_0 - W_1 )
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(distance)
```

This fails with this error:

> ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 1 but is rank 0 for
>   'gradients/GatherNd_3_grad/ScatterNd' (op: 'ScatterNd') with input
>   shapes: [2], [], [2].

I tried embedding the distance scalar into a 1-dim tensor, but it gives a similar error:

```
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(tf.stack([distance]))
```

Any idea what is wrong with the above graph?

Comment: It would be easier to have `DEPTH`, `initia` and the value you feed into `I`.

Comment: it fails before any evaluation, `initia` is just `tf.zeros.initializer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify you `indices` argument such that it's a list of single element positions

```
O_0 = tf.gather_nd(O, [[0, 0]]) # if DEPTH is 2
W_1 = tf.gather_nd(W, [[0, 1]])
```

it will work fine:

```
DEPTH=2

initia = tf.zeros_initializer
I = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name='I') # input
W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[1,DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # weights
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[DEPTH], initializer=initia, dtype=tf.float32) # biases
O = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(I, W) + b, name='O')
O_0 = tf.gather_nd(O, [[0,0]])
W_1 = tf.gather_nd(W, [[0, 1]])
distance = tf.square( O_0 - W_1 )
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(distance)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(train_op, {I: [[1], [2], [3]]}))
```

You'll find more information on the `indices` argument in the documentation:

> Gather slices from `params` into a Tensor with shape specified by `indices`.
>
> `indices` is an K-dimensional integer tensor, best thought of as a
>     (K-1)-dimensional tensor of indices into `params`, where each element defines a
>     slice of `params`:

```
  output[i_0, ..., i_{K-2}] = params[indices[i0, ..., i_{K-2}]]
```

> Whereas in @{tf.gather} `indices` defines slices into the first
>     dimension of `params`, in `tf.gather_nd`, `indices` defines slices into the
>     first `N` dimensions of `params`, where `N = indices.shape[-1]`.
>
> The last dimension of `indices` can be at most the rank of
>     `params`:

```
  indices.shape[-1] <= params.rank
```

> The last dimension of `indices` corresponds to elements
>     (if `indices.shape[-1] == params.rank`) or slices
>     (if `indices.shape[-1] < params.rank`) along